# removeAtIndex and removeObjectAtIndex is missing in autosugesion in latest xcode

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

Hello I am working on swift. I want to delete a row from tableView. The problem is that there is no option of remove object from an array is coming in autosuggestion. is there any other method apple has introduced to delete a row. I can't find these two methods `removeAtIndex` and `removeObjectAtIndex`. My array datatype is this

```
 var array = NSArray()
```

see [image]

Comment: Is it NSArray or NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray` is *immutable* so you cannot remove items from it. You have to use `NSMutableArray` which allows modifications.